# Sorting Vecor by multiple columns

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm trying to sort a vector by multiple columns. So heres my vector, where rows is the numbers of rows. Because I use the vector in a for-loop for different sizes, it has to be dynamicly.

```
vector<vector<double> > matrix;
matrix.resize(rows);
for(size_t i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    matrix[i].resize(3);
}
```

After the vector is set up, I fill it with data. The data consist of coordinates (xyz).

```
for(size_t i = 0;i<lss.size();i+2) {
            int k = i+1;
            matrix[i][0]=lss[i].v[0].x;
            matrix[i][1]=lss[i].v[0].y;
            matrix[i][2]=lss[i].v[0].z;
            matrix[k][0]=lss[i].v[1].x;
            matrix[k][1]=lss[i].v[1].y;
            matrix[k][2]lss[i].v[1].z;
    }
```

So far everything works fine. But next I have to sort the vector. What I know from my data is the z-coordinate is always the same, for one loop passage. So I would have to sort the vector by it's first and than by the second column. I already search for sorting functions, like std:sort, I couldn't find something suitable. My attempt was this:

```
int compare(vector<double>& s1, vector<double>& s2)
{
    return s1[0] < s2[0];
}   
std::sort(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), compare);
```

But the result was the same as the input.

So the unsorted output looks like this:

```
X=-5.000000, Y=2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=2.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=2.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-2.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-2.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
```

What I want is:

```
X=-5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-2.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=-2.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=2.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=2.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=-2.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
X=5.000000, Y=5.000000, Z=-2.000000
```

Comment: Return type of your compare function should be `bool`. But that shouldn't preclude the sort from working. Please post MCVE, which coould be copy-pasted, compiled and run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to sort based on the first two columns, the compare function needs to use both values. Also, change the return type of `compare` to `bool`
and the argument types to `const&`.

```
bool compare(vector<double> const& s1, vector<double> const& s2)
{
    // If the values of the first column are not equal,
    // just use them to order s1 and s2.
    if ( s1[0] != s2[0] )
    {
       return s1[0] < s2[0];
    }

    // If the values of the first column are equal,
    // use the values of the second column to order s1 and s2.
    return s1[1] < s2[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your tip, and it worked perfectly fine.